# How to get minimum values in dataframe below a certain threshold?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, euclidean-distance

I have 2 dataframes in pandas containing locational information of cars and trees.

df1

```
                 x       y   
         car
          3     216     13    
          4     218     12    
          5     217     12
```

df2

```
                 x       y    
          tree 
          5     253     180    
          6     241     24    
          8     217     14
```

How would I go about calculating the euclidean distance between each car and each tree, and then filter out distances that are less than eg: 5? I would like to create another dataframe with the car and tree number, and the distance between the two (see below)

df3

```
         car   tree    dist     
          5     8      2.2
```

So far I can use

```
 distance = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(df1, df2, metric='euclidean')
```

to get the euclidean distances for everything, but I am struggling to select the values I need (i.e. distances < 5).
Help appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: "Filter out" means "remove". You seem to want to subset/select instead.

Comment: yes that's what I mean - editing my question now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
distance = spatial.distance.cdist(df1, df2, metric='euclidean')
idx = np.where(distance < 5)
pd.DataFrame({"car":df1.iloc[idx[0]].index.values, 
              "tree":df2.iloc[idx[1]].index.values,
              "dist": distance[idx]})

    car dist        tree
0   3   1.414214    8
1   4   2.236068    8
2   5   2.000000    8
```

- The (i, j) entry of `cdist` is the distance between the ith item in first group of items and jth item in the second group of items.
- We use `np.where` to identify the (i, j) pairs in `distance` that satisfy the condition `distance < 5`.
- We built a new dataframe with the index gained from the last step. `idx[0]` gives the part in `df1` we need to retrieve and `idx[1]` gives the part in `df2` that we need to get.

Comment: @UserR6 sure :P

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
import pandas as pd
from toolz import concat
import scipy

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 216, 13],
                    [4, 218, 12],
                    [5, 217, 12]],
                   columns=['car', 'x',  'y'])
df1 = df1.set_index('car')

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 253, 180],
                    [6, 241, 24],
                    [8, 217, 14]],
                   columns=['tree', 'x',  'y'])
df2 = df2.set_index('tree')

indices = list(map(list, zip(*[(x, y) for x in df1.index for y in df2.index])))
distance = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(df1, df2, metric='euclidean')

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'car': indices[0], 'tree': indices[1], 'distance': list(concat(distance))})

df4 = df3[df3['distance'] < 5]
```